# RoR: Export CSV process asynchronously using a worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to use a Sidekiq worker to handle CSV downloads in the background. Ordinarily a user clicks a button and the csv downloads right away. I'd like to process the csv asynchronously in a worker:

In my User model:

```
def self.generate_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << [I18n.t('models.user.csv_header.email'),
           blah blah
  all.each do |user|
    csv << [user.email_i18n,
           blah blah
  end
end
```

In my User Controller:

```
    format.csv do
      #what I normally do
      #response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
      #response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{@models.camelize}.csv"
      #send_data @collection.generate_csv, filename: "#{filename}.csv"
---------------------------------------------------------------
    
      CsvDownloadWorker.perform_async(@collection, filename)
    end
```

In my CsvDownloadWorker:

```
 class CsvDownloadWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
  
    sidekiq_options queue: :default, retry: 0

    def perform(collection, filename)
      ????
    end
end
```

I have no idea where to go from here and have tried various convoluted approaches with no success. I would really appreciate any guidance big or small. ty

Comment: I can help on how to run the generate CSV in background (then, for example of the CSV file to the user), but I don't know how to start download via Browser when CSV is created.

Comment: so since sidekiq will be running as a separate process which doesnt fall in the request-response cycle for http you cannot give the csv file as response if you are generating it asynchronously. How ever you have other options, you can implement some sort of polling mechanism or you can use your own websocket based solution or use 3rd-party solutions like pusher.com